# .NET Core Object JSON Serialization to Javascript format

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I've some problems with serializing my C# objects into a plain JSON string.

I user JsonConvert ( Newtonsoft's one) to format a model into a JSON. The problem is that that JSON string get's used in some Javascript, but the format is not good as in a quote gets written down as ""e;" instead of "'". Any idea's on how to fix this ?

```
//...
@{
    var dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
}
//...

<script>
    function ChangeGroup(type) {
        $.ajax({
            url: //...,
            data: @dataJson
        });
    }
</script>
```

what I get is this:

[image: error]

Some formatting options I forget to set ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto doing this gives me the type of the model in the data part.

Comment: Please reopen this question. There's a better way to do this in ASP.NET Core (not available in the duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@{
  var dataJson = new HtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
}
```

By default ASP.Net Core will HTML encode before rendering an @ expression unless the expression evaluates to a type with the interface IHtmlContent (which HtmlString has). Another way is to write

```
@Html.Raw(dataJson)
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a much shorter, easier to use and remember in ASP.NET Core:

```
@Json.Serialize(Model);
```

When assigned to a JavaScript value, the resulting JavaScript is valid:

```
<script>
    var model = @Json.Serialize(model);
</script>
```

With this, you don't have to worry about HTML-escaping the characters.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt What? The question is how to serialize JSON so that it can be used in javascript

Comment: Ah my bad, didn't noticed the `IJsonHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following to get data out of my model into a JS object. Thought I would post to possibly help someone in the future...

```
var items = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Items));
```